# Add until a certain value is reached and return the content of another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

So I have the given table.

[image: Table]

The formula will be in `B6`. The problem look like this: first I need to test if `B2` is >= than `B5`. If it is I need to return `B1` (Week 1), else add `B2+C2` and test if the sum is >= than `B5`. If it is return `C1` (Week 2) and so on.

I know how to do it with function `IF` but there are 50 columns.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem by yourself?

Comment: I do not know what to try

Comment: You said in your question that you *know* how to do that with `IF` but now you say you don't even know what to try?

Comment: Yes I know with if but it becomes a long function: =IF(B2>=B5,B1,IF(B2+C2>=B5,C1,IF(B2+C2+D2>=B5,D1,"and so on until 50 columns")))

Comment: It is normal for complex functions to be long. Would you mind adding your formula to your question?

Comment: So i need this to calculate for 52 weeks couse that is the number of weeks within a year and i would done it if excel let me enter that many arguments in a function

Comment: https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: IFS function: https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/excel/functions/ifs-function-in-excel/

Answer (score 0):

IF one has BYCOL and LAMBDA, available in Office 365:

```
=INDEX(B1:G1,IFERROR(MATCH(B5,BYCOL(B2:G2,LAMBDA(a,SUM(B2:a))))+1,1))
```

`BYCOL(B2:G2,LAMBDA(a,SUM(B2:a)))` returns an array of the sums.

Then the MATCH finds where the the qty lands and returns that to the INDEX.  The IFERROR is there incase the qty is reached on the first week.

Note: this does not work if the numbers in the array are negative as it will give a false positive.

[image]

if one does not have Office 365 we can use OFFSET in a SUMIF to return the array:

```
=INDEX(B1:G1,IFERROR(MATCH(B5,SUMIF(OFFSET(B2,0,0,1,ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,COUNT(2:2)))),"<>"))+1,1))
```

This may require the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

`SUMIF(OFFSET(B2,0,0,1,ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,COUNT(2:2)))),"<>")` does the same as the BYCOL/LAMBDA above.

[image]

But given all of the above, it would be easier if one would just do the running total below the row:

```
=SUM($B$2:B2)
```

Put that in B3 and drag copy over.

[image]

Then just use the INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX(B1:G1,IFERROR(MATCH(B5,B3:G3)+1,1))
```

[image]